# how to stop execution and echo user a message when no rows return

Tags: php, oracle

I have two php pages first one **index.php** as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Site Title</title>
</head>

<body align="right">

<h4 align="right">Site Title<br>Subtitle</h4>

<form action="acc_data.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ACCNUM"> Account Number</br>
<input type="submit" value="Search">

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

and **acc_data.php** as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Site Title</title>
</head>

<?php

$conn = oci_connect('admin', 'admin', 'localhost/JDT','AL32UTF8');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Prepare the statement
$sqlstr = 'SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,CUST_NAME,PHONE1 FROM customers where CUSTOMER_ID=:ACCNUM';

$stid = oci_parse($conn,$sqlstr);
$ACCNUM = $_POST['ACCNUM'];
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':ACCNUM', $ACCNUM);
oci_execute($stid);


// Fetch the results of the query
print "<table style=width:75% align=center border=1>
        <tr><th>Account Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th></tr>";

        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
        {
            print "<tr>";
            foreach ($row as $item) 
            {
                print "<td align=center>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>";
            }
            print "</tr>\n";
        }
print "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

the user in first page will enter its data and pass the value to another php page to be processed at server and return back the result

question 1: 
is there any security improvement should I do?

question 2: 
in case of no rows return how to stop execution and echo user a message?

Comment: a: for q2: use a conditional statement. `if(condition is met){ do something } else{...}`. In a nutshell.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok but how to know if the statment return somethign or not i found oci_num_rows but its not working as i searched it not return number of rows fetched

Comment: see these Q&A's http://stackoverflow.com/q/17782007/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/18957148/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23425684/ those should give you something to use to check if there were rows found.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Oracle API doesn't provide a function that just returns the number of rows int he result set. The only way I can see to tell how many rows were selected is to fetch all the rows before printing anything. So use [`oci_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) to fetch all the rows at once.

```
$count = oci_fetch_all($stid, $rows, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW + OCI_ASSOC);
if ($count == 0) {
    Print "No results found";
} else {
    print "<table style=width:75% align=center border=1>
            <tr><th>Account Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th></tr>";

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        ...
    }
    print "</table>\n";
}
```

Comment: its always return No results found even there is record its display No results found and don't show records

Comment: Oops, left out some of the arguments. Try it now.

Comment: return message when no result found, but return null when record should found without message which is mean that its get out of if statment but it lose the result ?

Comment: I don't understand why. I did it just like the examples in the documentation. I don't have Oracle so I can't test it.